# State is undefined while passing prop to react router

Tags: react-router

ArticleItem.js

```
<Link to="/articlePage" state= {{ heading: heading }} target="_blank">
                continue reading...
</Link>
```

From ArticleItem.js component I want to send heading to ArticleSoloPage component

```
const location = useLocation();
    useEffect(()=>{
      console.log(location);
    },[])
```

{pathname: '/articlePage', search: '', hash: '', state: undefined}
But there state is undefined

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Link like this:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/articlePage",
    search: "?sort=name",
    hash: "#the-hash",
    state: { heading: heading }
  }}
>
  continue reading...
</Link>
```

Read this:
https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html#

Comment: Still state is undefined

Comment: In the functional component did you try: props.location.state ?

Comment: in which component you are talking, in which I am sending or receiving??

Comment: The component you link to -> /articlePage

Comment: ×
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'heading')
ArticleSoloPage
src/pages/ArticleSoloPage.js:6
  3 | 
  4 | const ArticleSoloPage = () => {
  5 |   const location = useLocation();
> 6 |   const heading = location.state.heading;
  7 |   useEffect(() => {
  8 |     console.log(heading);
  9 |   }, []);

Answer (score 1):

you have the state within "to" and then catch it like this:

```
  <Link
      to={{
        pathname: "/articlePage",
        state: { heading: heading }
      }}
  >
   continue reading...
  </Link>
```

now on the other side:

```
const location = useLocation();
const heading = loaction.state.heading;

useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(heading);
  alert(heading);
},[])
```

Comment: Still {pathname: '/articlePage', search: '', hash: '', state: undefined}  state is undefinded

Comment: have you caught it like this "const heading = loaction.state.heading;"

Comment: yeah i did then error came

Answer (score 1):

then you can try it by useHistory() like this, instead of Link use any other tag like Span, div, or any other.

```
   import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"
   const history = useHistory();

   <div onClick={()=> history.push({pathname: "/articlePage",
        state: { heading: heading }
})
}>
//your statements
</div>

and then catch it like this :

const currentState = history.state
```